# Aggregate function in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, oracle11g

I have three tables and I want this:
For each skill, started during 2016 and part of at least two training packs and completed with a score between 12 and 17, list the skill ID, its category, its level, the number of training packs which is part of and its average score.

I wrote the code below but there is problem when I select the avg and sum.

```
select SKILLNUM , SKCATEGORY , SKLEVEL , count(TPID)
from (trainingpack t join Is_part_of i on t.TPID=i.TPID join skill s on i.SKILLNUM=s.SKILLNUM)
where STARTINGDATE like '%2016' and COMPLDATE is not null and score between 12 and 17 
and (SKILLNUM) in (
select is_part_of.SKILLNUM
from is_part_of
group by SKILLNUM
having count(TPID) >=2);
```

Also I tried this code

```
select SKILL.SKILLNUM , SKILL.SKCATEGORY , SKILL.SKLEVEL ,count( IS_PART_OF.TPID),sum( IS_PART_OF.SCORE)
from SKILL,TRAININGPACK,IS_PART_OF
where TRAININGPACK.STARTINGDATE like '%2016' and IS_PART_OF.COMPLDATE is not null and IS_PART_OF.score between 12 and 17 
and IS_PART_OF.TPID=TRAININGPACK.TPID and IS_PART_OF.SKILLNUM=SKILL.SKILLNUM and (is_part_of.SKILLNUM) in (
select is_part_of.SKILLNUM
from is_part_of
group by SKILLNUM
having count(TPID) >=2);
```

Comment: show sample tables

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using. Then see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You may need to add the other columns in the group by clause. so GROUP BY SkillNum, SkCategory, SkLevel

Comment: please don't spam tag. You've been asked which RDBMS you're using but failed to respond. If you left the question only to return at a later date, then remove the redundant tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aggregate functions` without a `group by` sentence, only if you don't include other columns in your SELECT clause.

e.g: You can use the below `select` sentence in your query, but you will not get a report by SKILLNUM, SKCATEGORY and SKLEVEL as you expect.. You will get only the global count and sum results:

```
select count( IS_PART_OF.TPID),sum( IS_PART_OF.SCORE) from ...
```

As you are looking a report by SKILLNUM, SKCATEGORY and SKLEVEL, you should include a `group by` clause at the end of your query:

```
... group by SKILL.SKILLNUM , SKILL.SKCATEGORY , SKILL.SKLEVEL
```

So, without knowing exactly your db model, your query should be:

```
select SKILL.SKILLNUM , SKILL.SKCATEGORY , SKILL.SKLEVEL ,count(   IS_PART_OF.TPID),sum( IS_PART_OF.SCORE)
from SKILL, TRAININGPACK, IS_PART_OF
where TRAININGPACK.STARTINGDATE like '%2016'
and IS_PART_OF.COMPLDATE is not null
and IS_PART_OF.score between 12 and 17 
and IS_PART_OF.TPID = TRAININGPACK.TPID
and IS_PART_OF.SKILLNUM = SKILL.SKILLNUM
and is_part_of.SKILLNUM in (
select is_part_of.SKILLNUM
from is_part_of
group by SKILLNUM
having count(TPID) >=2)
group by SKILL.SKILLNUM , SKILL.SKCATEGORY , SKILL.SKLEVEL
```